# Insert file into SQL field and extract back into file

Tags: filesystems, mysql, sql

I created simple table:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
CREATE DATABASE observe;

USE observe;

CREATE TABLE `see_me` (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name VARCHAR(20),
food VARCHAR(30),
confirmed CHAR(1), 
signup_date DATE,
file_contents LONGBLOB // or VARBINARY(MAX)
);
```

and a file called t.txt. How can I insert the file into the field file_contents with sql commands and extract it likewise into a file?

The insert may be something like

```
 INSERT INTO see_me(id, file_contents) 
 SELECT '1', BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '/Users/usr_00/lab/t.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) as ...;
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: OPENROWSET is Microsoft SQL (SQL Server) syntax. In MySQL use [LOAD_FILE Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).

Comment: I am seeing this 
**
mysql> UPDATE see_me
    ->             SET file_contents=LOAD_FILE('/Users/usr/lab/t.txt')
    ->             WHERE id=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
**

however, the table remains unchanged.

Comment: *the table remains unchanged* Check: 1) account have `FILE` privilege 2) file is posessed in `secure_file_priv` folder 3) File do not exceed `max_allowed_packet` in size 4) account have `READ` rights on the file in filesystem.

Comment: file privilege is ok, access is ok. file size is small.

Comment: Does `@@secure_file_priv='/Users/usr/lab/'`?

Comment: what is the exact command line?

Comment: Search MySQL User Manual by the variable name and study.

Comment: Not there. The command above stated was from there and it did not work.